# How to get RSSI of Wifi on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, rssi

I want to get RSSI of wifi in iPhone.
I know that, we can get by Mobile Wifi.framework.

I Implement like in this page: http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework

... but it doesn't run: I still can't get the RSSI in iOS 5.0 and more.

Comment: Please check my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167577/using-private-api-to-read-wifi-rssi-value/48083845#48083845

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add an entitlement to your project using the *com.apple.wifi.manager-access* key. The creation of the entitlement differs from the Xcode version you are using (.xml, .entitlement), but your entitlement's content should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>YOUR_APP_BUNDLE_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.manager-access</key>
    </true>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Second, you need to have a Jailbreak and AppSync on your iOS device in order to launch your app, this is due to the entitlement.

I had the same problem at the beginning, maybe [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303981/ios6-1-problems-while-trying-to-access-wifi-rssi-mobilewifi-framework) can give you further information.