# Using Private API To read WiFi RSSI Value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on something that will not need to be on the App store, so I have no issues with using private APIs to meet my needs
I'm trying to use the `MobileWiFi. framework to read the RSSI value for the wireless network the phone is currently connected to. I've included the`https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/tree/c613e45f3ee5ad9f85ec7d43906cf69ee812ec6a/MobileWiFi` headers and used a bridging header to include them in my swift project and wrote the code as follows. Please excuse me, I am a newbie.

```
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork
typealias _WiFiManagerClientCreate = @convention(c) (CFAllocator, CInt) -> UnsafeRawPointer
typealias _WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices = @convention(c) (UnsafeRawPointer) -> CFArray
typealias _WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty = @convention(c) (UnsafeRawPointer, CFString) -> CFPropertyList

if let libHandle = dlopen (Paths.ipConfiguration, RTLD_LAZY) {
        result = libHandle.debugDescription

        let _createManagerPtr = dlsym(libHandle, "WiFiManagerClientCreate")
        let _clientCopyDevicesPtr = dlsym(libHandle, "WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices")
        let _clientCopyPropertyPtr = dlsym(libHandle, "WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty")

        if (_createManagerPtr != nil) && (_clientCopyDevicesPtr != nil) && (_clientCopyPropertyPtr != nil) {
            let _createManager = unsafeBitCast(_createManagerPtr, to: _WiFiManagerClientCreate.self)
            let _clientCopyDevices = unsafeBitCast(_clientCopyDevicesPtr, to: _WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices.self)
            let _clientCopyProperty = unsafeBitCast(_clientCopyPropertyPtr, to: _WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty.self)

            let manager = _createManager(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
            let devices = _clientCopyDevices(manager)
            let client = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, 0)

            let data = _clientCopyProperty(client!, "RSSI" as CFString)
            let rssi = CFDictionaryGetValue(data as! CFDictionary, "RSSI_CTL_AGR")

            NSLog("RSSI: \(rssi)")
        }

        dlclose(libHandle)
    }
```

Which yields an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value which stems from trying to call _createManager`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this workaround:

```
+ (int) wifiStrength {
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}

return[[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"wifiStrengthRaw"] intValue];
}
```

Works without any entitlements or jailbreaking

Answer (score 5):

Since the Status bar in iPhone X is different from other iPhones, the ways to get WiFi information are different.

Here is the workaround on how to get it via "**undocumented properties**", which means Apple might change these properties in the future without letting us know.
The App will crash if Apple changed the **undocumented properties** but we didn't adjust our code accordingly. So we have to handle the NSException in Swift.

Create a Header file, and add it in your Bridging-Header.h.
You can find the file [here:https://gist.github.com/zhihuitang/6d3de0963d96a552d47721a598ca79c8](https://gist.github.com/zhihuitang/6d3de0963d96a552d47721a598ca79c8)

```
//
//  OCCatch.h
//
//

#ifndef OCCatch_h
#define OCCatch_h

// add the code below to your -Bridging-Header.h

/**
 #import "OCCatch.h"
 */

//   How to use it in Swift?
/**
 let exception = tryBlock {
        let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        //......
    }
  if let exception = exception {  
    print("exception: \(exception)")
  }  
*/

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_INLINE NSException * _Nullable tryBlock(void(^_Nonnull tryBlock)(void)) {
    @try {
        tryBlock();
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return exception;
    }
    return nil;
}

#endif /* OCCatch_h */
```

In iPhoneX, we can get **numberOfActiveBars** of WiFi, which ranges from 0 to 3.
In other iPhones other than iPhoneX, we can get WiFi RSSI.

On iPhoneX, please use `getWiFiNumberOfActiveBars()`:

```
 private func getWiFiNumberOfActiveBars() -> Int? {
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    var numberOfActiveBars: Int?
    let exception = tryBlock {
        guard let containerBar = app.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView else { return nil }
        guard let statusBarMorden = NSClassFromString("UIStatusBar_Modern"), containerBar .isKind(of: statusBarMorden), let statusBar = containerBar.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView else { return nil }

        guard let foregroundView = statusBar.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as? UIView else { return nil }

        for view in foregroundView.subviews {
            for v in view.subviews {
                if let statusBarWifiSignalView = NSClassFromString("_UIStatusBarWifiSignalView"), v .isKind(of: statusBarWifiSignalView) {
                    if let val = v.value(forKey: "numberOfActiveBars") as? Int {
                        numberOfActiveBars = val
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            if let _ = numberOfActiveBars {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if let exception = exception {
        print("getWiFiNumberOfActiveBars exception: \(exception)")
    }

    return numberOfActiveBars
}
```

On iPhone devices other than iPhoneX, please use `getWiFiRSSI()`:

```
private func getWiFiRSSI() -> Int? {
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    var rssi: Int?
    let exception = tryBlock {
        guard let statusBar = app.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView else { return }
        if let statusBarMorden = NSClassFromString("UIStatusBar_Modern"), statusBar .isKind(of: statusBarMorden) { return }

        guard let foregroundView = statusBar.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as? UIView else { return  }

        for view in foregroundView.subviews {
            if let statusBarDataNetworkItemView = NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView"), view .isKind(of: statusBarDataNetworkItemView) {
                if let val = view.value(forKey: "wifiStrengthRaw") as? Int {
                    rssi = val
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let exception = exception {
        print("getWiFiRSSI exception: \(exception)")
    }
    return rssi
}
```

So far I haven't found a way to get WiFi **RSSI** on iPhoneX. If you guys know how to do it, please also let me know. thanks.

here is the [demo project](https://github.com/zhihuitang/WiFiSignal) in Github

Comment: What is strange is that someone like ARWifiScanner and Dr.Wifi does actually show the db signal value, also on iPhone X, so it _is_ possible. However when speaking directly to Apple Engineers they say there is no way (obviously they mean documented way) but still.

Comment: The ARSignalMaster takes a screenshot of the statusbar, detects how many bars there are and then sets a dBm value and a little random number generator around it. So fake

Comment: I did an educational decompile of their solution, since the Apple Technician our company had a dialog with specifically said they did not use the hotspot helper API but would not otherwise specify how it could be done.

Comment: Doesn't compile. You need to return nil in your `guard` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible for the latest version of iOS. It is possible upto iOS4 only.

Comment: I managed to get the code to build, but it seems like it won't work because of the entitlements needed, it should work on a jailbroken phone

Comment: No, because you can't get the entitlement you'd need for it to run

Answer (score -1):

[rssi and other stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN9gf.jpg)

ios 17 opened Wi-Fi API's which could be levegared in wireless testing.

in order to use it:

upgrade to ios 17
download shortcut
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/f4aa1682c2b241bd838bf60dba0a3bae