# Get cellular signal from statusbar crash

Tags: ios11, xcode9, uistatusbar, iphone-x

Below is my code and I am trying to get signal strength through status bar.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
```

**Crash occurred on (iOS 11, Xcode 9, iPhone X):-**

[UIStatusBar_Modern valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key foregroundView

Comment: What you want? Wifi Signal? No of bars?

Comment: No of active bar of wifi signal? or SignalMode?

Comment: @KiranJasvanee I want network type 3g, 4g, Wifi, LTE ..

Comment: For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167577/using-private-api-to-read-wifi-rssi-value/48083845#48083845

Answer (score 6):

you can use this

```
NSArray *subviews = nil;
id statusBar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
if ([statusBar isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBar_Modern")]) {
    subviews = [[[statusBar valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
} else {
    subviews = [[statusBar valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
}
```

Comment: I am having issue post this, from which key to get if wifi, 3g or lte is there .. ?

Comment: Thank you @yz wu this is exactly what I was looking for +1

Comment: @Ashish the above snippet of code solves the issue with iPhone X changes. To get the code you have to loop the subviews to extract `UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView` view and then get its `dataNetworkType` value. It goes something like this.


`for (id subview in subviews) {`

        `if([subview isKindOfClass:` 

`[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {`

            `[(NSNumber*)[subview valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"] 
intValue]; // dataNetworkType value be sure to store and use it, or return it from a method`

          `break;`
       `}`
   `}`

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
- (NSString*)newtworkType {
    NSArray *subviews = nil;
    id statusBar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
    if ([statusBar isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBar_Modern")]) {
        subviews = [[[statusBar valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    } else {
        subviews = [[statusBar valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    }
    NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    switch ([[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"]integerValue]) {
        case 0:
            return @"No wifi or cellular";
            break;

        case 1:
            return @"2G";
            break;

        case 2:
            return @"3G";
            break;

        case 3:
            return @"4G";
            break;

        case 4:
            return @"LTE";
            break;

        case 5:
            return @"WIFI";
            break;


        default:
            break;

    }
    return @"";
}
```