# Obtaining Signal Strength Programatically in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, core-telephony

I've been trying to obtain the signal strength using Swift 4 with iOS 12. Using the documentation seems like a lot of methods are Deprecated or no longer working. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your issue could be solved by this: [A way to calculate or get wifi strength on Swift on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564350/a-way-to-calculate-or-get-wifi-strength-on-swift-on-ios-11)

But that seems to be not working @iOS12 anymore.

Looking at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67932 there seems to be no supported way to do this, but to use "illegal" private APIs.

Comment: So approving his concerns is a wrong answer? Sadly, there is no way right now. Simple fact.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.